# Macbook Air 2017 Computer Audio Through Microphone

Tags: mac, bootcamp, headphones

I have a MacBook Air 2017. Whenever I use headphones, any headphones, the people I’m in call can hear what I do on my Mac such as the video I am watching or the game I am playing. This is no big deal for meetings but while gaming it frustrates me to use push-to-talk. It is not software related I believe since it happens on bootcamp also. Any idea why this is happening?

I also find out that built-in mics do not have this problem. Only happens with headphones.

Comment: The „why“ is easy to explain: the mic in your headphones picks up the noise of your keyboard etc. What kind of software do you use for calls?

Comment: That is not what I meant. My game sound or the video I am watching goes through the microphone. I use in-game voice chat in League and Fortnite, I also use Discord. Some problem everywhere.

Comment: Then please edit your question to clarify the problem.

Comment: Also: do you play the game sounds via the headphones or via the speaker of your Mac?

Comment: I play the sound on my headphones.

Comment: There's an outlying chance that your headset is wired for OMTP not CTIA. This would reverse the pins used for Mic & Ground. See https://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/